# Silverlight MVVM: Changing cell border color in DataGrid based on bound value in Silverlight

Tags: silverlight, mvvm

I am very new to Silverlight and am working on a project that is using the MVVM pattern.  What that means is that I do not want to write code-behind to accomplish this task (the solution architect is very clear on this requirement), but rather I am looking for a way to do it entirely in XAML.

I have two classes that look like this:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace SilverlightApplication2.ViewModels
{
    public class ClassA
    {    
        public long ClassAValueOne { get; set; }

        public ObservableCollection<ClassB> ClassBs { get; set; }
    }

}


namespace SilverlightApplication2.ViewModels
{
    public class ClassB
    {
        public long? ClassBValueOne { get; set; }

        public long? ClassBValueTwo { get; set; }

        public long? ClassBValueThree { get; set; }

        public long? ClassBValueFour { get; set; }
    }
}
```

A view model class that looks like this:

```
using System.Collections.ObjectModel;

namespace SilverlightApplication2.ViewModels
{
    public class EditorViewModel
    {    
        public EditorViewModel()
        {
            this.ClassAs = new ObservableCollection<ClassA>
            {
                new ClassA
                {
                    ClassAValueOne = 1,
                    ClassBs = new ObservableCollection<ClassB>
                    {
                        new ClassB { ClassBValueOne = 1, ClassBValueTwo = 2, ClassBValueThree = 3, ClassBValueFour = 4 },
                        new ClassB { ClassBValueOne = 5, ClassBValueTwo = 6, ClassBValueThree = 7, ClassBValueFour = 8 },
                        new ClassB { ClassBValueOne = 9, ClassBValueTwo = 10, ClassBValueThree = 11, ClassBValueFour = 12 }
                    }
                },
                new ClassA
                {
                    ClassAValueOne = 3,
                    ClassBs = new ObservableCollection<ClassB>
                    {
                        new ClassB (),
                        new ClassB (),
                        new ClassB ()
                    }
                }
            };
        }

        public ObservableCollection<ClassA> ClassAs { get; set; }
    }
}
```

And a view that looks like this:

```
<controls:ChildWindow x:Class="SilverlightApplication2.Views.ExemptionEditor"
           xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation" 
           xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml" 
           xmlns:controls="clr-namespace:System.Windows.Controls;assembly=System.Windows.Controls"
           xmlns:viewmodels="clr-namespace:SilverlightApplication2.ViewModels"
           xmlns:i="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactivity"
           xmlns:ei="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/2010/interactions"
           xmlns:toolkit="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/toolkit"
           xmlns:sdk="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation/sdk"
           Width="470" Height="700"
           Title="Exemption Editor">

    <controls:ChildWindow.DataContext>
        <viewmodels:EditorViewModel/>
    </controls:ChildWindow.DataContext>

    <i:Interaction.Triggers>
        <ei:PropertyChangedTrigger Binding="{Binding DialogResult}">
            <ei:ChangePropertyAction TargetObject="{Binding ElementName=ExemptionEditorChildWindow}" PropertyName="DialogResult" Value="{Binding DialogResult}"/>
        </ei:PropertyChangedTrigger>
    </i:Interaction.Triggers>

    <controls:ChildWindow.Resources>
    </controls:ChildWindow.Resources>

    <Grid x:Name="LayoutRoot" Margin="2">
        <Grid.Resources>
            <Style x:Key="DataGridTextColumnReadOnlyBackgroundColor" TargetType="sdk:DataGridCell">
                <Setter Property="Background" Value="#C6DEFE" />
            </Style>
        </Grid.Resources>

        <Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <RowDefinition />
            <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
        </Grid.RowDefinitions>

        <ListBox ItemsSource="{Binding ClassAs}">
            <ListBox.ItemTemplate>
                <DataTemplate>
                    <toolkit:Expander IsExpanded="True">
                        <toolkit:Expander.Header>
                            <Border Background="#FF99CC00">
                                <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ClassAValueOne}" FontWeight="Bold" Foreground="Black"></TextBlock>
                            </Border>
                        </toolkit:Expander.Header>
                        <StackPanel Orientation="Vertical">
                            <TextBlock Text="{Binding Path=ClassAValueOne, StringFormat='Enter data for item {0}'}" Margin="5,10,0,10" Foreground="Black" FontWeight="Bold"/>
                            <sdk:DataGrid ItemsSource="{Binding ClassBs}" AutoGenerateColumns="False" HorizontalAlignment="Center" VerticalAlignment="Center" RowHeight="20" Margin="0, 0, 0, 10">
                                <sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ClassBValueOne}" Header="ValueOne" FontWeight="Bold" Width="100" IsReadOnly="True" CellStyle="{StaticResource DataGridTextColumnReadOnlyBackgroundColor}"/>
                                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ClassBValueTwo, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="ValueTwo" FontWeight="Bold" Width="100"/>
                                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ClassBValueThree, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="ValueThree" FontWeight="Bold" Width="100"/>
                                    <sdk:DataGridTextColumn Binding="{Binding ClassBValueFour, Mode=TwoWay}" Header="ValueFour" FontWeight="Bold" Width="100"/>
                                 </sdk:DataGrid.Columns>
                             </sdk:DataGrid>
                        </StackPanel>
                    </toolkit:Expander>
                </DataTemplate>
            </ListBox.ItemTemplate>
        </ListBox>
    </Grid>

</controls:ChildWindow>
```

I have two UI requirements:

1. If any of the value properties in ClassB are null, the data grid cell representing that null value should have a red border around it to bring to the user's attention that they need to enter a value into that cell.
2. If a user tries to type a string into the cell for a value property of ClassB (which is typed as a nullable long), the cell background should turn red to bring to the user's attention that they can't enter a string value into the cell.

I've searched for possible ways to accomplish this, but everything I am finding is for WPF and refers to using a DataTemplateSelector, which doesn't exist in Silverlight.

Any help?

Answer (score 0):

That is easier than you think!
You just need to use some validation attributes.

Check out these links:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd901590%28v=vs.95%29.aspx

http://www.asp.net/mvc/tutorials/older-versions/models-%28data%29/validation-with-the-data-annotation-validators-cs

ps: there are some examples in aspx , but you can apply then to silverlight as well.

Good luck!

Comment: Thanks for your answer.  Unfortunately, that is not what my customer is looking for.  I started there because it was a very easy solution, however the customer has some very strict UI requirements.  Those requirements are as stated in my question.  They want very specific UI feedback which the data annotations do not provide.